# Adding dynamic fields to nested form through AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, nested-forms, railscasts

I've been watching and reproducing these railscasts on my app: [196-nested-model-form-part-1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) and [197-nested-model-form-part-2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2). I do not yet have a pro account so i can't watch the revised episode.

I'm developing under rails4 (edge) and `link_to_function` has been deprecated in favor of unobstrusive JS (which is great).

I'll keep the example of the above railscasts (i.e. survey/question).
What i'd like to do is to use the question's partial through unobstrusive javascript and i just don't know how and where i should do this.

I was thinking of two ways to do so :

- First way would be to add in my `app/assets/javascripts` a file `surveys.js` with the function `add_question` but i don't see how i could use my partial from here.
- Other way would be to create a new action in my `SurveyController` that would respond using the question partial but i'm bothered by the fact of having an action specific to questions in my survey controller.

I can't help to think there must be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't have a pro account on Railscasts either, but sometimes it is a good idea to have a look at [Ryan's Github account](https://github.com/ryanb). Oftentimes he develops gems to stuff he covered in his episodes. There you will find this awesome [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) gem, which does exactly what you want.

Of course you can reinvent the wheel, but I think it is much easier and faster to use Ryan's gem. The documentation explains perfectly how to use it. Have fun!

Comment: Thank you @Charles. I indeed found that nested_form gem but i didn't try it as it requires the use of `nested_form_for` and i'm already using `simple_form`. I'm not quite sure i can use both.

Comment: Yes, you can. Just use `simple_nested_form_for`. Check out [this](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form#simpleform-and-formtastic-support).

Comment: That's what i went for. I know have the pro account so i was able to watch the revised episode.

Comment: Looks like the build is currently failing and I don't see support for bootstrap_form_for.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 18):

Did you know about remote links and forms? You can use a remote link here to accomplish what you want.

In your view:

```
link_to 'Add question', add_question_path(@survey), remote: true
```

In your controller

```
def add_question
  @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js #add_question.js.erb
  end
end
```

The last step is to create a file app/views/surveys/add_question.js.erb

```
$('#my_survey').append('<%=j render partial: 'my_question_partial' %>')
```

Don't forget to create a route for your ask_question_path

For more info about remote links and forms see: http://tech.thereq.com/post/17243732577/rails-3-using-link-to-remote-true-with-jquery-ujs

Comment: Thank you @Arjan. That's indeed what i meant by creating a new action in my SurveyController but i wasn't quite sure about doing this for the reasons i explained above. Your solution, though, seems clean and dry. Failling to find an other solution, i will probably go for this.

Comment: why is there a j inside `<%=j render partial`

Comment: @Clam `j` is an alias for the `escape_javascript` javascript helper. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript

Comment: Does it applies for a nested form element ? The form's object has to be passed somewhere. It does not seem to answer what's asked