# Forms for nested_attributes (has_many: mobiles)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Contact Model

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :phonebook
    has_many :mobiles
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :mobiles
end
```

Mobile Model

```
class Mobile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :contact
end
```

Contacts Controller

```
def new
    @contact = Contact.new
end
```

Note:

1. Mobile model has details and type as attributes.
2. Contact model has name as attribute.

How do I write my form with rails helper to produce multiple mobile objects for a new contact instance?

This is my form

```
<h1>Create a new Contact</h1>
<h2>Add details</h2>
<% form_for(@contact) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_messages %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :name %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :mobile %><br />
        <% f.fields_for :mobile do |ff| %>
            <div>
                <%= ff.select :type,options_for_select([["HOME", "H"], ["WORK", "W"],["OTHER", "O"]])%>
                <%= ff.text_field :details %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Add Contact" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: At the time of creating a new contact, i want to accept multiple mobile details from the form like "home","work","other". I know how to get this work for one mobile detail. I'm stuck at getting more than one phone details from my form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms). You will need something like this in your controller:

```
def new
    @contact = Contact.new
    2.times { @contact.mobiles.build}
end
```

An explanation of what `build` does is to found in the [API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-build):

> **build(attributes = {}, &block) Link**
>
> Returns a new object of the collection type that has been instantiated
>   with attributes and linked to this object, but have not yet been
>   saved. You can pass an array of attributes hashes, this will return an
>   array with the new objects.

**Update**

If you want to add fields dynamically take a look at:

- [Adding dynamic fields to nested form through AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568431/adding-dynamic-fields-to-nested-form-through-ajax)
- https://github.com/lailsonbm/awesome_nested_fields

Comment: his `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is correct and his question is **How do I write my form with rails helper to produce multiple mobile objects for a new contact instance?** for which my answer applies!